# Adding Tumbling Window before Sink in Apache Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, spark-streaming, flink-streaming

There is a flink application. It takes in a datastream from a Kafka topic. Let's call this datastream `A`. `A` undergoes a lot of processing within this Flink app. Post all the processing, we get a datastream of type `<Headers, GenericRecord>`, where `Headers` are Kafka Headers and `GenericRecord` are Avro Generic Records following a certain schema `sch`. Lets call this new post-processed datastream as `B`.

`B` then flows into a sink Kafka topic which is then consumed by another Flink app. Now this second flink app has a lot of heavy procesing to do and hence, is a little slow. Due to this, there a heavy lag build up seen.

To counter this, a proposed solution which was offered was to add a Tumbling Window of time 10 seconds before the datastream enters the sink.

There is strict type checking happening everywhere so the type of datastream `B` needs to be the same before and after the tumbling window.

I tried to create a new datastrem `C` that collected the required data from B in the correct type format like so:

```
Datastream<Tuple2<Headers, GenericRecord> C = B
                    .keyBy((KeySelector<Tuple2<Headers, GenericRecord>, String>) value -> value.f1.get("id").toString())
                    .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
                    .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<Tuple2<Headers, GenericRecord>, Tuple2<Headers, GenericRecord>, String, TimeWindow>() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(String s, ProcessWindowFunction<Tuple2<Headers, GenericRecord>, Tuple2<Headers, GenericRecord>, String, TimeWindow>.Context context, Iterable<Tuple2<Headers, GenericRecord>> elements, Collector<Tuple2<Headers, GenericRecord>> out) throws Exception {
                            for (Tuple2<Headers, GenericRecord> tuple : elements) {
                                out.collect(Tuple2.of(tuple.f0, (GenericRecord) tuple.f1));
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

But I'm getting a type mismatch in GenericRecord.
Here's how the GenericRecord type info looks before the above code i.e. `B`:

`GenericRecord(" ...Avro schema here... ")`

But post the above code, the GenericRecord type info for `C` looks like this:

`GenericType<org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord>`

Why is this change in type info occuring? How do I fix it?

Comment: Adding artificial burstiness and lag into the first application seems like the wrong way to address the problem. It's hard to imagine how this will help. It just pushes the problem 10 seconds down the road, and causes the first job to use more resources.

Comment: Rather than collecting a new Tuple2.of(...), why not simply `collect(tuple)`?

Comment: @DavidAnderson The main purpose of the artificial bursts is to reduce the load on the database input operation. Also, `out.collect(tuple.f0,  tuple.f1)` would not work because collect requires only one argument. Which is `Tuple.of(...)` is used.